# How can I change scene by pressing a key in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I working on project like black mirror banderanatch. I create a movie that player has to interact with by pressing a specific key on keyboard to change to another scene. I dont know how to code it, I don't need a box or anything to click because in video I will say what button to press to go on another scene. I've tried put the video in UI in each scene but its does not work

some of the code I'm using

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ChangeSceneWithButton : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void LoadScene(string sceneName1)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName1);
    }
     if{keyboard.write() a;
LoadScene(sceneName1)}
     

}
```

what should I add to make it change scene with specific button

ps.first time using unity any advice please teach me

Comment: Your code isn't even compiling .... also please use correct tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the input in the `Update` function, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ChangeSceneWithButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _sceneName;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) SceneManager.LoadScene(_sceneName);
    }
}
```